# Where can I learn to do edge flows like in the attached image?

Tags: mesh

I am unable to create the edge flows in the below image. I have tried sculpting and retopo, but I just can’t recreate the ways it is done cleanly here. Is there a tutorial that I can follow that can help teach to do edge flows like this?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 6):

How to learn it : following good examples and practice a lot on different models.

Now as for good examples, it's nearly impossible as a beginner to even tell appart good and bad examples.

Years ago Danny Mac did two series of how to retopologize a head and human body on Youtube:

- [How to Retopologize a Head like a Boss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWEDWFMjA9E&list=PLud7kvRn-3hhfG6eMHmWdSYvHpijVfKZ8)
- [How To Retopologize the Rest of the Body](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ns5iRWRii5c&list=PLud7kvRn-3hhJz5Yn8wkAEYEUXdKD0jok)

They are not made on Blender, but what I found interesting here is that decomposes how to obtain shapes and flows.

You might want to have a look at CGCookies's Retopoflow, which adds a lot of retopology tools to Blender, akin to what 3D Coat or zBrush offer.
You can get it for free on [github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow), or you can buy it on [blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow](https://blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow) to support the devs and also be entitled to tool support.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try out the above resources :D

Answer (score 4):

I guess the main thing, that you probably already know, is that when you retopologize you need to create these concentric circles around the eyes and mouth. The circles around the mouth need to contain the bottom of the nose. It will allow you to work and animate more easily:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have seen the concentric circles. I guess i need to practice more to get it